# GridLayout merging all elements in top left corner

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to create a simple tic-tac-toe game for which I am using `GridLayout` for making board grid. When I put my `imageView` in GridLayout they all merges to the top-left corner of the gridLayout. I am using gridLayout on API-21. I've tried ever possible solution I can find on the internet.
Here's the XML of my activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
tools:context=".inGameActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/background"
app:columnCount="3"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:rowCount="3">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `layout_gravity`, to make the elements stay where you want, on GridLayout. By changing `fill` to the position of the grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            app:layout_gravity="top|left"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            app:layout_gravity="left"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It didn't worked out. Still the same everything on top-left corner. I made a tic-tac-toe game once and it was working fine. Now I am doing the same exact thing but its not working.